# ZF2 Use Annotations To Define Radio Button

Tags: php, annotations, zend-framework2

Is it possible to use Zend\Form\Annotation capabilities to create a radio button?

I am trying this right now:

```
/**
 * @Annotation\Type("Zend\Form\Element\Radio")
 * @Annotation\Options({"label":"Status"})
 */
public $status;
```

But I don't know how to pass radio button options through the annotation.

Any ideas? Ordinary text inputs work fine, i.e.:

```
/**
 * @Annotation\Filter({"name":"StringTrim"})
 * @Annotation\Type("Zend\Form\Element\Textarea")
 * @Annotation\Options({"label":"Description"})
 */
public $description;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was easy:

```
/**
 * @Annotation\Type("Zend\Form\Element\Radio")
 * @Annotation\Options({"label":"Status"})
 * @Annotation\Attributes({"options":{"1":"Enabled","2":"Disabled"}})
 * @Annotation\Required(true)
 */
public $status;
```